# Multiple mediator model with multiple groups in lavaan?

Tags: r-lavaan

I know how to run multiple mediator models in lavaan and multiple group models in lavaan, but I now want to compare mediation parameters across the 2 groups. However, when I define parameters, they are only printed for the first group, so I don't know if they are different for the second group or not. Is there a trick to doing that? I tried to define parameters as I would define path constraints for multigroup, e.g. c(z, z)*var (so, in this case, I tried something like: indirect effect: c((a1*b), (a1*b)), to make it print two outputs, one for each group, but it doesn't work), and I can't find anything on this topic online. Here is an example of a code:

```
Model <- 'LatentVar =~ c(z, z)*var1 + c(z, z)*var2 + c(z, z)*var3 
VarA~ c(a1, a1)*VarB + c(a2, a2)*LatentVar + c(a3, a3)*VarC
VarD ~  c(b, b)*VarA + c(c1, c1)*VarB + c(c2, c2)*LatentVar + c(c3, c3)*VarC
LatentVar ~~ VarA
LatentVar ~~ VarC
indirect_VarA := a1 * b
indirect_LatentVar  := a2 * b
indirect_VarC  := a3 * b
total_VarA  := c1 + (a1 * b)
total_LatentVar   := c2 + (a2 * b)
total2_VarC  := c3 + (a3 * b)'

fit<- sem(model = Model, data = dat, estimator= "MLR", missing = "FIML", std.lv = T, group = "group") 
summary(fit, standardized = TRUE, fit = TRUE, ci = T)
```

Thank you!
Maria

Answer (score 2):

For your purposes, the defined parameters **must have unique names for each group and each variable**, and must not be reused as you have done. Reworking your code like this should give you the estimates you want for each group:

```
Model <- 'LatentVar =~ c(z_v1_g1, z_v1_g2)*var1 + c(z_v2_g1, z_v2_g2)*var2 + ...
VarA~ c(a1_g1, a1_g2)*VarB +  c(a2_g1, a2_g2)*LatentVar + ...
VarD ~  c(b_g1, b_g2)*VarA + ...
```

Then for the parameter definitions, you need to specify each path you are interested in, in each group:

```
indirect_VarA (group 1) := a1_g1 * b_g1
indirect_VarA (group 2) := a1_g2 * b_g2
...
```

As an aside, reusing parameter names can be a used strategically depending on your model. For example, if you had three groups and wanted to fix the parameters of the first two to be equal for a specific variable, you could write something like

```
Var1 ~ c(a, a, b)*Var2
```

This will force *lavaan* to estimate equivalent parameters for the first two groups, but freely estimate it in the third.